# Display animation based on link # extension

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to set jQuery up to catch a # link and display an animation based on which one it picks up?

> **Example:**
>
> Click Link 1 > /index.php#1 = pulsate div 1
>
> Click Link 2 > /index.php#2 = pulsate div 2
>
> Click Link 3 > /index.php#3 = pulsate div 3

I currently have a guide/rule page, and it want it to highlight the correct content when people are taken there by a specific link. I understand basic jQuery animations, just not giving them rules from a parent page.

Comment: Yeah, sure, but have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: @Nit I have being trying to research into it, hence why I've posted on here as I'm now stuck with me having no luck.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Read hash from URI

JS's `window.location.hash` will read the hash like `"#1"` which is a **valid ID** in **HTML5**

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $( window.location.hash ).addClass("pulsate");
});
```

where you have **DIV** elements like

```
<div id="div1">I'm DIV 1</div>
```

and a **CSS** class like

```
.pulsate {
  /* other styles here... */
  animation: pulsate 0.5s ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: 5;                                    /* Pulsate 5 times */
}
@keyframes pulsate {
  0%    {transform: scale(1);}
  50%   {transform: scale(1.2);}
}
```

### 2. Read hash from clicked link

If you're not interested in reading the URI's hash but you have simply LInks like

```
<a class="animateButton" href="#div1">Animate DIV1</a>
```

than this is all you need:

```js
$(".animateButton").on("click", function(){
  $( this.hash ).addClass("pulsate").on("animationend", function(){
    $(this).removeClass("pulsate");
  });
});
```

```css
.pulsate {
  background: orange;
  animation: pulsate 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition:0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 3; 
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
  0%    {transform: scale(1);}
  50%  {transform: scale(1.1);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="animateButton" href="#1">#1</a>
<a class="animateButton" href="#2">#2</a>
<a class="animateButton" href="#3">#3</a>

<div id="1">I'm DIV #1</div>
<div id="2">I'm DIV #2</div>
<div id="3">I'm DIV #3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not rules *"from a parent page"*. You can get the hash parameter from a page's url by using `location.hash`:

```
//index.php#1
location.hash //-> will return #1

//index.php#2
location.hash //-> will return #2
```

Then, you can select it directly in your jQuery selector as `$(location.hash)`. This will enable you to animate the targeted div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Do your animation
    $(location.hash).animate(/*...*/)
});
```

**obs:**

Remember that divs with numeric ids are only valid in HTML5

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6rvtvv5/) that you play with it. I didn't add animations but left it to you as an exercise. =]

HTML

```
<a href="#section1">sec1</a>
<a href="#section2">sec2</a>
<a href="#section3">sec3</a>
```

JS

```
$("a").on('click', function(event){
    var t = event.target.toString();
    if (t.endsWith('1')){
        alert('animation 1');
    } else if (t.endsWith('2')){
            alert('animation 2');
    } else if (t.endsWith('3')){
            alert('animation 3');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you - that's purely what it's for, a learning excercise & knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

You have to listen to the hash changes.
Try to use a plugin like hashchange.

```
$(window).hashchange((function(){
      var hash = window.location.hash.replace("#",'');
  // remove previous animation from element if there's one

  if(hash) {
    // do your animation adding class or with pure jquery
  }
  return arguments.callee;  // return itself as the hashchange handler
})( )); // exec the first time and then at each hash changes
```

Remeber to remove the class or the javascript animation fron previuos pulsating element.

[jQuery hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/)